# Skybox textures is transparent

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, skybox

My skybox is displayed, but does not display the textures that I load from the image. Instead, it shows the transparent color if i set  `glTexImage2D` how `GL_RGBA`, or black color if i set  `glTexImage2D` how `GL_RGB`.

I am using [a render with MultisampledFbo support](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/master/src/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/fbo/MultisampledFbo2Demo.java).

My texture loading code looks like this:

```
private int loadSkyboxTextures(){
         glGenBuffers(vbo);
         glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
         glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, POINTS, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
         glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
         glGenVertexArrays(vao);
         glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
         glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
         glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 3 * Float.BYTES, NULL);
         glTexCoordPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 3 * Float.BYTES, NULL);        
         glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
         glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        int texID = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texID);
        for(int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_FILES.length; i++){
            InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEXTURE_FILES[i]);
            byte[] pixelData = new byte[0];
            try {
                pixelData = new byte[file.available()];
                file.read(pixelData);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pixelData);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0,
                    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
        }

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        return texID;
    }
```

Cube Render Code:

```
    private void drawSkybox(){
        glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
        glDepthMask(false);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texId);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDepthMask(true);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    }
```

The cube rendering call in the main render function:

```
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                view = viewX || viewY || viewZ;
                if(view)
                    glPushMatrix();

                int rot = 180;

                glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
                glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                glOrtho(-max, max, -1, 1, 10, -10);
                glRotated(cameraX, 1f, 0f, 0);
                glRotated(cameraY, 0f, 1f, 0);
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                glLoadIdentity();
                drawSkybox(texId);

                glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                ...
                //render camera and other objects
```

Comment: You don't specify the any texture coordiantes. Do you use a shader?

Comment: @Rabbid76 [My points (coordinate) array](https://pastebin.com/vHp3m2mV)

No. I do not use shaders

Comment: @Rabbid76 I did as you advised and changed the code in the my program and the main post, but the textures are still black

Answer (score 0):

For cube map textures, the texture coordinates are 3-dimensional and treated as a vector form the center of the cube map.
Since you draw a cube, which is centered around (0, 0, 0), you can use the the vertex coordinates for the texture coordinates, too. You do not use a shader program, so you have to use fixed function attributes. Specify the vertex coordinates by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) and the texture coordinates by [`glTexCoordPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml). Enable the client-side capability ([`glEnableClientState`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml)) `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` and `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`.

Specify the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). It is sufficient to execute that code once at intialization:

```java
glGenBuffers(vbo);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, POINTS, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenVertexArrays(vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);

glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.BYTES, NULL);
glTexCoordPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.BYTES, NULL);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

When you draw the skybox it is sufficient to bind the cubemap texture to enable cube-mapped texturing and to bind the VAO:

```java
private void drawSkybox(){
    GL11.glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
    glDepthMask(false);        

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texID);

    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glDepthMask(true);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
}
```

---

There are some further issues:

- The image is not read correctly. See [I have a black texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164578/i-have-a-black-texture/61167571#61167571).
- Clear the depth buffer after drawing the skybox. See [Skybox textures do not display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181470/skybox-textures-do-not-display-correctly/61182768#61182768)

Comment: I did as you advised and changed the code in the my program and the main post, but the textures are still black