# Skybox textures do not display correctly

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, skybox

I have a problem with skybox textures. If you twist the camera, it creates a feeling that one texture overlays another, as in the screenshot:

[image: example]

Skybox show code:

```java
private void drawSkybox(int texId){

    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
    glDepthMask(false);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texId);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDepthMask(true);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
}
```

My opengl paramters:

```java
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glColorMask (true, true, true, true);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
```

And my call drawSkybox:

```java
glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-max, max, -1, 1, 10, -10);
glRotated(cameraX, 1f, 0f, 0);
glRotated(cameraY, 0f, 1f, 0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
drawSkybox(texId);
```

How i can fix the problem?

I understand that the problem is `glDepthMask(false);` but how can it be replaced?

If I just remove `glDepthMask(false);` and replace it with an example with `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);` and `glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);` then the skybox will overlap all other objects and only it will be visible –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the depth mask or the depth test when you draw the skybox. Keep the depth test function `GL_LESS`.

```java
private void drawSkybox(int texId){

    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
    // glDepthMask(false); <---- DELETE

    // [...]
}
```

But clear the depth buffer again, after drawing the skybox. Draw the skybox first, then the skybox covers the entire screen. Then clear the depth buffer, thus all objects which are draw after, will cover the skybox:

```java
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// [...]

drawSkybox(texId);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// render other objects
// [...]
```